# Придставился/представился

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли я пишу?

`Какой-то кот, мною ещё не виданный, пришёл и представился.`

`Лео-котёнок, голодный, желая кушкать, пришёл и придставился (то бишь придставил своё тело / подошёл близко-близко) к моей ноге, трясь и прося кусочек рыбчонки.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Корректный** вариант по словарю:

*Какой-то кот, мною ещё не виданный, пришёл и **представился**.*

2. **Авторское** употребление слова, нужны кавычки:

*Лео-котёнок, голодный, желая кушкать, пришёл и "**приставился**" (то бишь **приставил** своё тело / подошёл близко-близко) к моей ноге, трясь и прося кусочек рыбчонки.*

**ПРЕДСТАВИТЬСЯ**,  св. 1. Назвать себя, знакомясь с кем-л.; отрекомендоваться. Позвольте п. П. гостям по всей форме.

**ПРИСТАВИТЬ**,  св. 1. что к чему. Поставить рядом, вплотную, придвинуть, прислонить к чему-л. П. лестницу к стене. П. кресло к окну.

**ПРЕД**, приставка. 1. (служит для образования глаг.). Указывает на предварительность, заблаговременность действия. Предвещать, предвидеть, предостеречь, предохранить, предсказать, предугадать.

Comment: А нельзя, что ль, без кавычек? Это же просто возвратная форма глагола *приставить*.

Comment: В словаре нет этого слова, и редактор его подчеркивает. Возвратный глагол – это уже другое слово, а не форма слова.  У нас есть пассивный залог (дом строится кем), но возвратный залог – это особый залог. Поэтому слово нужно считать авторским грамматическим неологизмом.

Comment: нет возвратной формы приставился от приставил, не выдумывайте

Comment: Я по словарям и грамматическим справочникам работаю, а вы?)  Вот здесь тоже есть https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Залог_(лингвистика)

Comment: Это очевидно и я проверил по нацкорпусу. Есть только приставилась: Проблема ножниц приставилась, как нож к горлу, с момента, когда естествознание вломилось в меня, — да так, что не оставалось времени ни на что другое.

Comment: Котёнок приставил свой бок к моей ноге - можно. А: Какой-то кот, пришёл и представился. - это значит кот сдох.

Comment: Это возвратный залог, кто же спорит.  Но это же не ФОРМА слова, вот о чем речь. И в данном примере  слово лучше в кавычки заключить. Ведь у вашего автора с его ножницами хорошее художественное воображение, там ему контекст в помощь.  Вот и не нужны кавычки.

Comment: почему не форма слова? кавычки не помогут, потому что это некорректно, кавычки нужны для неизвестных метафор. А если слова выдумывать бессмысленные и употреблять не к месту, то тут кавычки не нужны. Нормальности слову кавычки никак не придают.

Comment: Какой-то кот, пришёл и представился. - ну каламбуры же, смешно, но зачем из этого делать вопрос по грамматике. Для этого нужен отельный вопрос про толкование игры слов и каламбуров, но это не про грамматику. А если у вас слово в кавычках, некорректное, а в скобках расшифровка - это зачем? Если шутка, то не нужны кавычки, если не шутка, то зачем некорректное слово?

Comment: Как вам лучше объяснить, право, не знаю...)  Для чего и зачем нужна такая форма вопросов?  Чтобы уйти от стандарта и заставить подумать. Вот вам и то пришлось подумать, чтобы оценить вопрос.  О залоге мы с вами поговорили, о форме слова и самом слове, о том о сем. И даже не  без эмоций (ваше "не выдумывайте!").  Какой уж тут стандарт. И задавать такие  вопросы труднее, чем обычные (очень скучные) . Каламбуры при изучении грамматики и правописания – это весело, интересно и полезно! Мне уж точно))  Эмоциональное лучше запоминается, это все психологи знают.

Comment: эмоциональное, может, и лучше запоминается, но понимания не развивает, а развивает фрагментарность восприятия. Обезьяну можно тоже словам научить отдельным, можно эмоционально, но связанной речи от этого не получится. Вот вы пишите: 1 Корректный вариант по словарю - да? и что значит следующая фраза?

Comment: Дальше приведено предложение с правильной грамматической формой. А еще дальше (по тексту) кот назвал свое имя.  Ну мне так кажется... А вам?